# Remove month from the axisX in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How remove month everywhere except at the first day of the month and leave  the numbers days? Month must be written only one, first day each month. [image]
Now my code

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
```

Example https://jsfiddle.net/o5926erd/5/

Comment: Can you please put up your (working) code in a fiddle and share us the link?

Comment: Yes, i add example.

Comment: Little confused. Your example seems to be showing the first day of the month as per your requirement.

Comment: Month must be written only one, first day each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use labels.formatter function of your xAxis: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

```
formatter: function() {
  var xAxis = this.axis,
    previousMonth,
    date,
    newTicks = [],
    index,
    returnedString,
    months = this.chart.options.lang.months;

  Highcharts.each(xAxis.tickPositions, function(t) {
    date = new Date(t);
    if (date.getMonth() !== previousMonth) {
      previousMonth = date.getMonth();
      newTicks.push(t);
    }
  });

  index = newTicks.indexOf(this.value);
  date = new Date(this.value);
  returnedString = index >= 0 ? date.getDate() + '. ' + months[date.getMonth()] : date.getDate()
  return returnedString;
}
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: https://jsfiddle.net/o5926erd/8/